# How can I receive math symbols from an String and get their Dec value from ASCII in Java?

Tags: java, string, encode

I'm making a little project that can help me to take a String e.g. "7 Si PARPADRE ∈ {8, 9 99}" and identify that math symbols, e.g. "∈" and get the decimal value at ASCII table.

But when I check de String the IDE just resolve the symbol as "?" character.

I tried with this code

```
byte[] text = scanner.nextLine().getBytes(US_ASCII);
String string = new String(text, US_ASCII);
```

And I tried with all the StandarCharsets availables and this doesn't works.

My objective is to get the char var as: "∈" to later get the dec value, e.g. 8714.

Thanks, and regards.

Comment: Where in [US_ASCII](http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ascii.html) is that character?

Comment: "∈" is not in the ASCII character set. But that's okay; Java doesn't use ASCII. What your scanner's input can provide is an open question.

Answer (score 2):

`∈` is [Unicode Character 'ELEMENT OF' (U+2208)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2208/index.htm) (decimal 8712)<sup>1</sup>, which means that its character code is `0x2208`, and it is certainly not an ASCII character.

<sup>1) `∈` should not be confused with `∊` [Unicode Character 'SMALL ELEMENT OF' (U+220A)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/220a/index.htm) (decimal 8714).</sup>

To get the UTF-16 character code in Java, call `charAt()` and cast/assign to `int`.

```
String string = scanner.nextLine();
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) {
    System.out.println((int) string.charAt(i));
}
```

The above code will print `8712` for the `∈` character.

Comment: This codeblock throws: � : 65533.
In fact, al the answers throws the same issue.

Comment: @BrandonRG That would then be because the `Scanner` is reading from the console, and the console is not setup for UTF-8, so the console cannot even take the `∈` character. That is not a problem of Java, but of the console window. --- Or, if the `Scanner` is reading a file, the character encoding of the file is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

To get the codepoint value of a "character" in a string, give its UTF-16 code unit position

```
"∈".codePointAt(0)
```

It has to be from a String because char (Character) is one UTF-16 code unit, one or two of which represent a Unicode codepoint. Example:

```
"".codePointAt(0)
```

Comment: This is printing `8712`, is he just wrong about its value being `8714`?

Comment: @Nexevis See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57435545/5221149) for difference between `∈` (8712) and `∊` (8714)

Comment: @Andreas Ah thanks for the clarification, that is pretty confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `byte` as a data type – both in `getBytes()` as well as `byte[] text` – and that doesn't support values you're trying to use (such as "∈").

In Java, a `byte` has a range of -128 to 127 (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html). The `char` data type on the other hand, is much more capable:

> The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

If you use `char` in your code, things will work like you expect. First, get a character array (instead of byte) by calling `toCharArray()`. Then define `text` to be a `char[]` instead of `byte[]`.

This example below would print "∈":

```
String s = "∈"; // scanner.nextLine() returns a string; I'm just using String here as MRE
char[] text = s.toCharArray();
String newString = new String(text);
System.out.println(newString);
```

Comment: The original code converts string data (from `scanner.nextLine()`) to a byte array, then back to a string. The question is why are they seeing unexpected results in the final copy of the string. OP would have to address the reasoning for doing this conversion but my answer here shows how to do a similar conversion and get a working string at the end.